# Laravel 5 and Angular 6 routing issue

Tags: php, angular, laravel

I'm having issues when trying to consume a laravel route defined on the api.php routes. When running both (angular and laravel) independently they work fine, but I compiled the angular project and placed on laravel's public folder, changing the index.php to index.html and it loads perfectly (dashboard show's as it should etc). But the service returns an html... Not sure if this is the correct way to do this but...
Thanks in advance[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wja7u.png)

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this is not a best way to create a project with angular with laravel.

angular provide separate routing structure also laravel provide self routing.
you need to communicate both of them so you need to create a new url and send this url in you get, post.... request and receive in your laravel routing.

you need to get more information about laravel routing go here.
https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/routing